# dblfloatfix with multicolumn

Tags: multicol

I am working with dblfloatfix with multicol packages. Now I need to obtain something like this: http://www.geomechanics.caltech.edu/publications/pdf/andrade_avila_12.pdf

There you can see the figures 1 and 2, using the packages described above I obtain the behavior of figure 1 using:

```
   \begin{figure*}[t]
   \centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.1\textheight]{example-image-a}
   \caption{B caption}
   \end{figure*}
```

Now I need to obtain the behavior of figure 2, but disappears, when I used the combination of dblfloatfix and multicol packages. Can I get the behavior of figure 2?, using already dblfloatfix and multicol packages.

Comment: multicol package doesn't support floats at all, dblfloatfix works with the standard `[twocolumn]` option, not multicol. A full page figure in twocolumn need `figure*` instead of `figure`

Answer (score 3):

`multicol` package doesn't support floats at all, `dblfloatfix` works with the standard `[twocolumn]` option, not `multicol`.

For a full page figure in `twocolumn`, you  need `figure*` instead of `figure`.